# SQLAlchemy create model with spaces in column name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I setup a model with spaces in a column's name? Lik "653.232.44 Test Spalte"

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    653.232.44 Test Column= db.Column(db.String(128))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python variables cannot have spaces in their names or start with numbers, however SQL identifier names can contain arbitrary characters if they are quoted.

`"653.232.44 Test Column"` is not a valid python identifier.

call the python variable something else, like `test_column_653_232_44` and map it to a column named `"653.232.44 Test Spalte"`

```
test_column_653_232_44 = db.Column('653.232.44 Test Column', db.String(128), quote=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing it as the `name` argument to [Column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__):

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    c653_232_44_test_column = db.Column("653.232.44 Test", db.String(128))
```

This assumes that the database will find such a name acceptable.  On the Python side, valid identifiers cannot begin with a digit or contain dots or spaces: you'll need to create a name that Python will accept.

Unless you really need to do this - for example you're mapping to an existing database with such a column - I'd recommend avoiding this practice: it will make writing raw SQL queries painful and annoying.